# Where can I find OpenJDK JVM crash log

Tags: java, log, location, jvm

One of my java application crashed. I want to find the JVM log to see what happened. Where can I find JVM logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it is in user home directory and and named hs_err_pidxxxx.log where xxxx is the PID number.